# Java System.in not working with custom stream

Tags: java, io, system.in

I am currently designing a chat application in Java. Therefore I created my own `JFrame`. All contents written to `System.out` are written into a `JTextArea` and I want to redirect `System.in` to use my `JTextField`. I wrote a simple class what should handle this:

```
public class InputField extends InputStream implements KeyListener {
    private JTextField textField;
    private String text = null;


    public InputField(JTextField textField){
        this.textField = textField;

        textField.addKeyListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException {
        //System.out.println("CALLED!");
        while (text == null)
            ;

        int b;

        if (Objects.equals(text, "")) {
            b = -1;
            text = null;
        } else {
            b = text.charAt(0);
            text = text.substring(1, text.length());
        }

        // System.out.println("GIVING: " + b);

        return b;
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
            text = textField.getText();
            System.out.println("ENTER: "+ text);
            textField.setText("");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {}
}
```

My reading mechanism:

```
StringBuilder cmd = new StringBuilder();
int b;

try {
    while ((b = System.in.read()) != -1)
        cmd.append(b);
    // Do something with cmd
} catch (IOException e){}
```

The first time I input any text and press enter, it works just fine. After outputting a message the `read()` function is called, but if I try to enter more text the `read()` function isn't called anymore. Any suggestions to fix this?

Take a look at [this](https://ibb.co/edej35) image.

Comment: I assume this is because your reading mechanism stops when it encounters `-1` for the first time, which happens at the point when you finished "sending" first message out. And after that you never restart the reader, and you also never fully reset your input stream (it doesn't block on read anymore because `text` would not be null)

Comment: I added an image as a reference. Take a look at that

Comment: I've literally no idea how that image could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first time you hit enter, it sets the `text` to `""`. Then this block sets `b = -1`:

```
if (Objects.equals(text, "")) {
        b = -1;
```

Which is the value that `read` returns, which makes your main loop finish.

Comment: But the text changes as I press enter and if it isn't `""` then b is equal to the first char of the text.